# Rendering inline styles as well as pre-defined styles for React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React's render method, if I'm looping through an array and rendering resulting elements, how can I use both pre-defined `style` objects as well as styles that depend on the arguments provided in the `map` callback when rendering a component?

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {

    const otherStyles = {
      height: '20px',
      backgroundColor: 'blue'
    }

    return (
      {this.props.items.map((d, i) => {
        return (
           // also include otherStyles
           <div style={{width: i * 10 + '%'}}></div>
        )
      }}
    )
  }
}
```

I'd like to avoid putting *all* of the styles inline as the return value, but rather only declare those styles that depend on arguments from the `map` callback.

**Is there a way to include an additional style object in conjunction with inline styles when rendering a component inside of a loop?**

Comment: Object.assign. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/assign

Comment: Right, this is a perfect use case for Object.assign, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two great options with ES6. As Dayan mentioned Object.assign or you can use object destructuring, also an ES6 feature.

```
const otherStyles = {
  height: '20px',
  backgroundColor: 'blue'
}

const inlineStyle = {
  width: '10%'
}

const deconstructed = {...otherStyles, ...inlineStyle}
const assign = Object.assign(otherStyles, inlineStyle)
```

both result in :

```
{
  height: '20px',
  backgroundColor: 'blue',
  width: '10%'  
}
```

More specifically, I put both options in the render method below:

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {

    const otherStyles = {
      height: '20px',
      backgroundColor: 'blue'
    }

    return (
      {this.props.items.map((d, i) => {
        return (
           // also include otherStyles with destructuring
           <div style={{width: i * 10 + '%', ...otherStyles}}></div>
        )
      }}
      {this.props.items.map((d, i) => {
        return (
           // also include otherStyles with Object.assign
           <div style={Object.assign(otherStyles, {width: i * 10 + '%'}}></div>
        )
      }}
    )
  }
}
```